# How to set jbytearray directly from file

Tags: c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have the following native code that copies from a file into a buffer and then copies the
contents of that buffer into a jbytearray.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test(JNIEnv * env, jobject){

 int file_descriptor = 100;
 JNIEnv * jni_env = env;
 FILE* file = fdopen(file_descriptor, "r");
 unsigned char* buffer;
 int size_of_file = 1000000;
 fread(buffer, 1, static_cast<size_t>(size_of_file), file);
 imageArr = static_cast<jbyteArray>(jni_env->NewByteArray(static_cast<jsize> (size_of_file)));
 jni_env->SetByteArrayRegion (imageArr, 0, static_cast<jsize>
    (size_of_file ), (jbyte*)buffer);

}
```

As this code runs in a loop, I would like to optimize this as much as possible. Is there any way to directly read from the file to the jbyteArray? I am aware jbyteArray is a pointer to a struct. Is there any way to set the fields of this struct directly instead of using the setByteArrayRegion() function?

If not, is there any other function that I can use to read from a file to a jbytearray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.  You can probably do it, but it probably wont be much faster and if something with the implementation changed in the JVM your code would stop working.  You are dealing with file I/O so I don't think SetByteArrayRegion is your real bottleneck here.

Comment: Do you know where I could find the definition of the jbyteArray class? Google's not very helpful..

Comment: AFAIK the [JNI Type Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html) is the only official reference for that sort of stuff.  They do state that "the jvalue union type is used as the element type in argument arrays."  Its unclear if that is how jarrays are always represented.  There is also GetPrimitiveArrayCritical/ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical which **might** do what you are looking for.  The jbyte type is "signed 8 bits" so casting back and forth with unsigned char should work.